# Can not edit/select tags from web interface(can not ask questions)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I am posting this from the mobile app as I am not able to post any questions or edit tags from the web interface. After writing the question I am not able to select a tag. Writing the text `bug` also does not help. When I hit the post I get the message

> You should select at least one tag.

I get the same behavior on both Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and Windows (Server 2008 R2) with both Chrome and Firefox. I think this is a very serious issue as posting questions/tag edits are core functionality.

Comment: Well, how did you ask this question then? :P

Comment: @MadaraUchiha OP is posting this from the mobile app

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have mentioned this in the question

Comment: Can anyone edit/add tags? Is it an issue only for me?

Comment: Now I have a same problem ;).

Comment: Nah, it's a bug, someone removed a `placeholder` attribute and it caused a jQuery setter to become a getter which returns `undefined` instead of what was expected.

Comment: I think it's gone away now !!! ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah that's me trying to secretly push out the new site navigation. That worked well... ;-)

I've temporarily rolled back while I fix the bug.

Comment: Well it's new navigation with reduced options ;)

Comment: Bug? So it wasn't a secret feature to quietly block me from asking crap? Whew! :P

Comment: @codeMagic it's part of SE's long term ambition for this - https://xkcd.com/810/